# SQL database query grouping results by ChildrenIDs as well as subChildrenIDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have this `[Folders]` table in SQL Server 2008:

```
TABLE [dbo].[Folders]
(
    [FolderID] [NUMERIC](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SubFolderOf] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [FolderName] [VARCHAR](128) NOT NULL
)
```

Here is the data in that table

```
[ID]  [SubFolderOf] [FolderName]
------------------------------------------------
1      0             Main [ROOT]
2      1             Technical And Development
3      1             Sales and Marketing
4      1             Legal
5      1             Finance
6      1             Departments
7      1             Compliance
8      2             Test Scripts
9      2             Documentation
10     2             Files
11     8             AV Training
12     8             AV Finance 1
```

The `[SubFolderOf]` column is a child of the `[ID]` column.

For example notice that ID#12 (`AV Finance 1`) is a subfolder of ID#8 (`Test Scripts`) which is a subfolder of ID#2 (`Technical and Development`).

I haven't been able to write the query which would return the below results

```
[ID]  [Field Name]
----------------------------------------------------------
1     Main
2     Main >> Technical and Development
11    Main >> Technical and Development >> AV Training
12    Main >> Technical and Development >> AV Finance 1
3     Main >> Sales and Marketing
4     Main >> Legal
```

Could somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Be great to see what you tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I didn't have the knowledge to try too much at all. I'm just now learning about joins. @John-Capelletti gave me exactly what I was looking for below. I'll be dissecting it and learning from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear if you are skipping levels in the desired results, but it seem you are looking for a recursive CTE.  I'm pretty sure this is 2008 compatible.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[SubFolderOf] int,[FolderName] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,0,'Main [ROOT]')
,(2,1,'Technical And Development')
,(3,1,'Sales and Marketing')
,(4,1,'Legal')
,(5,1,'Finance')
,(6,1,'Departments')
,(7,1,'Compliance')
,(8,2,'Test Scripts')
,(9,2,'Documentation')
,(10,2,'Files')
,(11,8,'AV Training')
,(12,8,'AV Finance 1')

Declare @Nest   varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by ID) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,SubFolderOf 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,FolderName 
            ,Path = cast(FolderName as varchar(500))
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  [SubFolderOf]=0
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.ID)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.SubFolderOf 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.FolderName 
            ,cast(p.path + ' >> '+r.FolderName as varchar(500))
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.SubFolderOf  = p.ID)
Select A.ID
      ,A.SubFolderOf 
      ,A.Lvl
      ,FolderName = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.FolderName
      ,Path
 From cteP A
 Order By Seq
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: This is outstanding! It's dynamic so I can add as many subfolder >> subfolder >> subfolders as needed. There are many keywords in there I'm not conversant with so in addition to this working right off the bat, there's a bunch of new stuff for me to learn. Thank you for that!

Comment: @Gregbert Alwats happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options, you can either self-join the table a couple times (left join) or you can use “recurring cte’s” which is a common table expression. I find the self-join easier to work with. You need to define how many times or levels you can maximum have e.g. 3 levels deep, 5, or 10.

Something like this:

```
select F.FolderId, concat(isnull(F3.FolderName, “”), “>>”, isnull(F2.FolderName, “”), “>>”, F.FolderName) as [Field name] from Folders as F
left join Folders as F2 on F2.FolderId = F.SubFolderOf
left join Folders as F3 on F3.FolderId = F2.SubFolderOf
```

You can eliminate the redundant “>>” by eg using a `case` expression or similar.

Comment: This approach will not directly output the special case of parent folders.

Comment: @avery_larry yes it will, because of my concat